# jQuery! Написание плагина?

Tags: jquery, javascript, объекты, плагин

Обычно я вижу кучу примеров создания плагинов уже к существующим DOM-объектам, выглядит это примерно так:

```
jQuery.fn.plugin = function(options){ return something; }
```

и используется

```
$('obj').plugin(options);
```

а как создать плагин безобъектный, т.е. чтобы его можно было вызвать вот так:

```
$.plugin();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery.plugin = function(options) {...}
```

Вопрос закрыт.